# Keep html dom manipulation on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to make a comment section using just html, and javascript. I create a new dom element when the user presses post, but when you refresh, obviously it goes away. How can i make it add permanently. I'd like to do this without a database because I've never used one before.

Here is the html:

```
<form class="commentForm">
    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="6" cols="50" required="required"></textarea><br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-submit" style="margin-right: 25%;" onclick="postComment()">Post</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function postComment() {
    var message = document.getElementById("comment").value;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.width = "500px";
    div.style.height = "50px";
    div.style.color = "black";
    div.innerHTML = message;

    document.getElementById("comments").appendChild(div);

    document.getElementById("comment").value = "";
}
```

Comment: You might consider using [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for this, but really a DB/session server-side is the right way to go.

Comment: Any local solution, like cookies or localStorage, would only be visible to the individual -- not all users.

Comment: You can use local storage as everyone says, but why do you want to do this without a server side? I see it's a comment example and is supposed to be viewed by someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: use `localStorage`.

Create a function with only purpose to add one div based on a value in your comments:

```
function addNewDiv (message) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.width = '500px';
    div.style.height = '50px';
    div.style.color = 'black';
    div.innerHTML = message;
    document.getElementById('comments').appendChild(div);
};
```

To manipulate localStorage, you should use `getItem` and `setItem` methods like this:

```
function saveItem(message) {
    var comments = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('comments') || '[]');
    comments.push(message);
    localStorage.setItem('comments', JSON.stringify(comments));
}
```

Now, update your current function to use those functions above:

```
function postComment() {
    var message = document.getElementById('comment').value;

    addNewDiv(message);
    saveItem(message);

    document.getElementById('comment').value = '';
}
```

All your comments are saved. To load them on F5-refresh, use this script after your HTML has been rendered:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('comments') || '[]').forEach(addNewDiv);
```

You are all done, to clear the localStorage, use:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Or:

```
localStorage.removeItem('comments');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This might sound stupid, but where do i call the postComment function. How does this all tie togethor?

Comment: It's ok i figured it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies to store the text area data. Hope this helps. The timer below reads the text box every 5 seconds so it will auto store the data.

```
setInterval(timer, 5000);

var com = document.getElementById("comment");

function timer() {
    var text = com.innerHTML;
    document.cookie = "text_area="+text;
}

window.onload = function(){
    if(readCookie("text_area")){
      com.innerHTML = readCookie("text_area");
    }
}

//Read cookies reads all cookies and returns the value from name variable

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
```