# Can anyone give me an easy way of making a darkMode and lightMode on a HTML page using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a website but I'm having trouble making a dark/light theme using JS. Does anyone know an easy way to make a dark/light theme?

- My idea is fetching elements with a certain style and changing it's CSS color property.

I tried using document.getElementsByClassName() but it made too much of a hassle. It's also really inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your colours using [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).

(You will want more colours than this example)

```
body {
    --main-bg-color: yellow;
    --main-fg-color: black;
}
```

Then override them in a dark mode stylesheet:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    body {
        --main-bg-color: black;
        --main-fg-color: yellow;
    }
}
```

Then, if you want the user to be able to toggle with your own UI as well as using their system wide choice, define them again with a class:

```
body.lightMode {
    --main-bg-color: yellow;
    --main-fg-color: black;
}

body.darkMode {
    --main-bg-color: black;
    --main-fg-color: yellow;
}
```

Then just use those variables when you want color name:

```
h1 {
    color: --main-bg-color;
}
```

If you want the UI to change the style then:

```
function eventHandler() {
    const b = document.body;
    if (b.classList.contains("darkMode")) {
         b.classList.remove("darkMode");
         b.classList.add("lightMode");
    } else {
         b.classList.remove("lightMode");
         b.classList.add("darkMode");
    }
};
```

Comment: Also, do you know how to keep the theme upon page refresh?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132502/keeping-js-changes-on-dom-after-refresh

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53460615/keep-html-dom-manipulation-on-refresh